# Implementing A Mail app-like User Interface

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am trying to implement a user interface that is similar to the iPhone's Mail app.

- The main screen displays a table. From the table the user can select a cell, at which point the next screen is launched. At the bottom, there is a bar showing a short text and an icon.
- The second screen displays the details of the cell. It will also be a table display. The bottom bar shows icons associated to this screen.

What kind of layouts do I use to implement this in Xcode?
1. Do I use a View controller, add a View and embed a TableView and a Toolbar inside that view?
2. Do I use a Table View Controller and add a Table View inside it and use the bottom tool bar that comes with the table view?

[image: Main Screen] [image: Second Screen]

In the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html), under 'Recommendations for Creating and Configuring Table Views,' it says 'Use an instance of a subclass of UITableViewController to create and manage a table view.' When I use this, the bottom bar can only be fixed or disappear when going back and forth between two screens via segue. That makes me wonder whether I should just use a View controller which is against the recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a **UIViewController**

### Why?

If you are going to display more than a `tableView` then it is recommended to use a `UIViewController` for the storyboard.

`UIViewController` are much more flexible. I guess your confusion comes from the following documentation line:

> Use an instance of a subclass of UITableViewController to create and
>   manage a table view

This does not mean you must to drag and drop a `UITableViewController` on the storyboard. It means your class need to inherit from  `UITableViewController` or at least implement the `deleguate` and `datasource` methods.

You would use  `UITableViewController` only and only if you need to display a `tableView`.

Comment: I have just tried it by implementing `UITableViewSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` and it seems to be working. Thanks.